# Make Image visible true in a button click event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have  image in my aspx page and i want to make it visible true in an button click event .
.I made it as visible false in pageload and again making visible true in the button click event...

Please any one can solve my problem

Comment: OK so just set `Visible` to `true` on button click and `false` on `Page_Load`, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div> 
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn_green" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" Text="Upload" /> 
</br></br> 
<asp:Image ID="imgprogress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/images/loading__a.gif" /> </div> 



    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
imgprogress.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add `OnClick` handler to call the function:

```
<asp:Button ID="Click" Runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="ShowImage" />

public void ShowImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    imageObject.Visible = true;
}
```

Comment: here is my code<div>              
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn_green" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click"
                        Text="Upload" /> </br></br>                      
                        <asp:Image ID="imgprogress" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/App_Themes/images/loading__a.gif" />                                        
                </div> protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        divupldprogress.Visible = true;}